# How to convert full screen Mobile VR into split screen to use with google daydream or oculusrift?

Tags: react-360

Right now I see full screen version of VR on my mobile browser. I want to convert into 2 split screen so that one can use it with google daydream or any other VR headset.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to enable WebVR support in Chrome on Android by going to `chrome://flags#enable-webvr`. Then you should see a "View in VR" button in your app that will activate stereoscopic view.

[image: view in vr button]

If you have a Oculus headset + Caramel browser or a Samsung GearVR headset + compatible phone then stereoscopic 3d should work out of the box and the button should always be visible. https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs/vrbrowsers.html

Answer (score 0):

To make your app work with DayDream or Oculus, you need their SDKs imported. If building app with Unity, download GoogleVR package, go to player settings and check the "Virtual Reality Supported" checkbox under other settings. After selecting virtual reality supported, you would find the options like DayDream/Oculus etc. Select the platform you want to build for. This should work.